# Detect 2 or more children in a cell of a WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Suppose I have a **WPF** **Grid**, all of its children belong to the same class, that properly implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class MyObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public int Row {get;set;}
   public int Column {get; set}
   public int IsOverlap {get; set}

   etc.....
}
```

In my actual project I have a **ListView** whose ItemsPanel is a grid (which displays the MyObject types above):

```
  <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="GridPanelItemsTemplate">
        <Grid  IsItemsHost="True" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

This is the ItemsSource (From several collections):

```
   <CompositeCollection x:Key="CombinedCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection1}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection2}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection3}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection4}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection5}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
```

...where MyCollection1 to 5 are a type of

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject>
```

Here is the ListView:

```
 <ListView  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource GridPanelItemsTemplate}" 
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}" />
```

When the ListView loads and there are more than 1 child in a particular cell, all the children in that cell should have IsOverlap=True. In the program the user can move multiple children to other cells simultaneously, and if so the system should check again and set IsOverlap to true or false depending on how many children are in each cell. (It also means when a child moves,its previous cell will lose count and its new cell will gain count). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The question is very broad, especially lacking any details, never mind a [mcve]. There are many different ways to solve it. However, you should focus on the view model side. IMHO, one good way to do it is subscribe to the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event on the collection, before you add anything, and then every time an item is added or removed, modify a count in a dictionary where the key is the row/column address (e.g. `Tuple<int, int>`), and then use that count as the value for the view model's checked state.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have updated the question to be more specific.